# How to write the rule something like "any character but excepts..." in ANTLR4?

Tags: antlr

For example in rfc2047

```
token = 1*<Any CHAR except SPACE, CTLs, and especials>
especials = "(" / ")" / "<" / ">" / "@" / "," / ";" / ":" / "
<"> / "/" / "[" / "]" / "?" / "." / "="
```

Write all permitted characters for token rule 
or 
how to combine especials rule?

Answer (score 3):

ANTLR 4 includes an *inclusive* set notation similar to regular expressions. The set can then be negated by using the `~` operator. Here are two examples showing an inclusive and exclusive set.

```
LETTER : [a-zA-Z];
NOT_LETTER : ~[a-zA-Z];
```